# How does google reflect changes(like file rename) in one tab to other tab in drive?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, client-side, web-storage

For example, I opened a document named "Doc1" from my drive. If I rename it to "Doc2" from the drive explorer, the opened document in the other tab gets reloaded and changes it's name. I want to know exactly how google does this? I learnt somewhere that it uses Html5 storage for this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably server side. When you update `page A`, request is sent to the server which then updates the changes on all your open pages, including `Page B`

Comment: probably websockets or a polyfill of it

Comment: @LiYinKong have tracked the network logs, but it doesn't show any use of websockets

Comment: @Cristy How do server updates the opened pages?

Comment: @Manu The page can poll for changes, can receive socket events that data was updated, there are a lot of ways you can achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely implement this using HTML5 *localStorage*. Whenever the script in any of the open tabs adds or changes an item stored there, the other tabs receive a "storage" (or "onstorage" for IE) event.

If you give each document a unique identifier, and store a dictionary mapping identifier->filename for all open files, you can change those names from any tab. Or you can simply store an array of files that need updating, and have the tabs reload themselves (including their updated "filename") from the server.

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan for answering. Do you any other interesting use cases of Html5 storage.